# python manage.py syncdb error: No module named south. Django installation outside Virtualenvwrapper called

Tags: python, django, django-south, virtualenvwrapper

I have Django installed in a `virtualenvwrapper` instance on which I've installed South. However 
When calling `python manage.py syncdb` the Django installation outside of the `virtualenvwrapper` is called and does not find `south`. How do I fix this?

```
    [~/devground/django_gilgamesh]# pip install south
Downloading/unpacking south
  Downloading South-0.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (135kB): 135kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: south
Successfully installed south
Cleaning up...
(django_gilgamesh)sdye@dy-borg.com [~/devground/django_gilgamesh]# python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/sdye/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in   execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/sdye/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/sdye/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/sdye/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/home/sdye/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/home/sdye/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/home/sdye/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/home/sdye/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/home/sdye/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named south
```

EDIT: I've tried both 'south' and 'South' in settings.py. The settings.py file is shown below.
EDIT: Replaced traceback with new traceback generated using 'south' in settings.py and re-installing south
EDIT2: Output of `which django-admin.py` /home/sdye/.virtualenvs/django_gilgamesh/bin/django-admin.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'p3)1ravw(zzt25-$tj0fd@r8^i1(0b1==tuk5e3ph32k8yjs20'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'south',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_gilgamesh.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_gilgamesh.wsgi.application'
```

Update: When testing on the command line `import south` gives ImportError: No module named south

Comment: What is the output of `which djando-admin.py`?

Comment: It is `south`, not `South` Make sure you have `south` in `INSTALLED_APPS` and not `South`

Comment: What is the output of `pip freeze` from inside the virtualenv?

Comment: /home/sdye/.virtualenvs/django_gilgamesh/bin/django-admin.py

Comment: Any hints on things to try next? Right now I'm just reading through other south issues

Comment: I should mention if I comment out 'south' in settings.py it runs smoothly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: It appears python looks for south outside of the virtualenvwrapper instance. When I installed south after closing the virtualenv the migration worked. This creates another problem I will post in a new thread.

NOTE:  since i'm using django installed in the virtualenvwrapper instance this should not happen

Anyone have an Idea how to fix this or a better explanation as to why this is happening?

Comment: same problem... searching for your new queastion.   Cannot find it.   Not a problem for me with south, but all using conda and evertying is form outside the virtual env!!!